# How to unlock Gnome's keyring with a FDE password at system boot?

Tags: boot, password, encryption, gnome-keyring

Is it possible to unlock Gnome's keyring (Seahorse) by entering the full disk encryption (FDE) password when Ubuntu 17.10 is booting? At the moment, I have to enter two passwords, the FDE password and subsequently my user password, in order to unlock my keyring, where f.i. the Firefox logins are stored.

The full disk encryption (FDE) was done with Ubuntu's graphic installer (called Ubiquity).